# What is an elegant / efficient way of storing the status of 100 lessons for multiple users?

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I'm working on an app in JavaScipt, jQuery, PHP & MySQL that consists of ~100 lessons. I am trying to think of an efficient way to store the status of each user's progress through the lessons, without having to query the MySQL database too much.

Right now, I am thinking the easiest implementation is to create a table for each user, and then store each lesson's status in that table. The only problem with that is if I add new lessons, I would have to update every user's table.

The second implementation I considered would be to store each lesson as a table, and record the user ID for each user that completed that lesson there - but then generating a status report (what lessons a user completed, how well they did, etc.) would mean pulling data from 100 tables.

Is there an obvious solution I am missing? How would you store your users progress through 100 lessons, so it's quick and simple to generate a status report showing their process.

Cheers!

Comment: I think you are messing _table_ with _rows_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table structure I would recommend would be to keep a single table with non-unique fields `userid` and `lessonid`, as well as the relevant progress fields. When you want the progress of user `x` on lesson `y`, you would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM lessonProgress WHERE userid=x AND lessonid=y LIMIT 1;
```

You don't need to worry about performance unless you see that it's actually an issue. Having a table for each user or a table for each lesson are bad solutions because there aren't meant to be a dynamic number of tables in a database.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the exact logic I was missing - cheers

Answer (score 1):

If reporting is restricted to one user at a time - that is, when generating a report, it's for a specific user and not a large clump of users - why not consider javascript object notation stored in a file? If extensibility is key, it would make it a simple matter.

Obviously, if you're going to run reports against an arbitrarily large number of users at once, separate data files would become inefficient.

Discarding the efficiency argument, json would also give you a very human-readable and interchangeable format.

Lastly, if the security of the report output isn't a big sticking point, you'd also gain the ability to easily offload view rendering onto the client.

Comment: This is a great idea. I already store the lesson content in this format, so perhaps I will use this idea to cache and display the data until it changes, and then re-populate the file with the userid/status table mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Use relations between 2 tables.  One for users with user specific columns like ID, username, email, w/e else you want to store about them.
Then a status table that has a UID foreign key.  ID UID Status etc.

It's good to keep datecreated and dateupdated on tables as well.

Then just join the tables ON status.UID = users.ID

Answer (score 1):

A good option will be to create **one** table with an user_ID as primary key and a status (int) each row of the table will represent a user. Accessing to its progress would be fast a simple since you have an index of user IDs.

In this way, adding new leassons would not make you change de DB

Comment: Ah yes, I hand't thought about this... an entire status table. Thank you!